# Is is possible to use the AsyncFileUpload from the AjaxControlToolkit in a .Net 2.0 project?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, .net-2.0

The title pretty much says it all.  I have a project that for political reasons cannot be moved to a later version of .Net and would love to have a drop-in control for uploading files better than the old FileUpload control.

I'd like to use the AsyncFileUpload control, but it's not in the latest version of the toolkit that is supported in the 2.0 framework.

I've looked at some of the flash based controls, but integrating them would trigger a full regression test of the project I'm on (multiple weeks).

We've lived with the FileUpload control because our files are small, but the error handling when a file gets larger won't be unacceptable much longer.

-- EDIT --
I just found Uploadify.  At first I didn't think it would work, but I checked out the forums any way.  I found this link http://www.uploadify.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=142&p=8620&hilit=asp.net#p8620  It works great.  I can do whatever I want to in the upload handler.

Comment: you should post your Edit as the answer if this works for you and mark it so.  That will close out the question and allow others to quickly find an accepted solution while searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm adding this as an answer for whoever follows:

I just found Uploadify. At first I didn't think it would work, but I checked out the forums any way. I found this link http://www.uploadify.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=142&p=8620&hilit=asp.net#p8620  It works great. I can do whatever I want to in the upload handler.

Comment: Hi Brad, I click the link, but it is no more there? Can you please share the code with me? Can you please email me on toakhtar@hotmail.com I would grateful to you. Thanks in Advance :)